# Error in ts[, y]: object of type 'closure' not indexable

Tags: r, time-series

I want to have code that decomposes all my time series, and then group all the rest/remainder (of the decomposition) of all my time series into a ggplot.

I know this code is not that but it should be a first step but it gives me this error.

I am trying to do that code :

```
ts_dec <- lapply(colnames(df33), function(x) {decompose(ts[, x], type = "additive")})


Error in ts[, x]: object of type 'closure' not indexable
```

"df33" is my dataframe with more than 50 timeseries in it.

Comment: Where is `ts` defined? There is a built in function called `ts()` that creates a time series object. But it's not clear why you have `ts[,x]` since you can't subset a function. Did you mean to have `df33[, x]`? or `ts(df33[, x])`. It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: FYI, in R a "closure" is a function (and its enclosing environment). When you see an error like that, look in your expression to see objects/symbols that are also functions (in R or in whatever you write/use). In this case, the only one that comes to mind is `ts` which is `stats::ts`. Other common culprits for this error are when people are looking for data named `data` or `df`, both of which are functions in R.